# how to pass variable from a file to another using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, d3.js

I am getting data from an api and i would like to pass it to another file using d3.js to create a barchart. Here the code where I get the data:

```
//app.js file

app.get("/getAlbumData",(req,res)=> {
    Wasabi.find( { publicationDate: { $gte : 2006, $lte : 2016}}, function (err, doc) {
            console.log(doc)
            res.send(doc);
            res.end();

    }).limit(25).forEach(function(data)
    {
        for(var i in data)
        {
            if(data[i]==null || data[i]=='')
            {
                delete data[i]
            }
        }
        result.push(data)
        return result

    })
})
```

I would to pass the variable "**result**" to the following file to use it in the function d3.json:

```
//barchart.js

 d3.json(result, function (data) {

        let filteredData=[];
        console.log("data", data[0])
        data.forEach((d,i)=>{
        
            if(d.country != undefined ) {
                if (d.country.localeCompare(country) == 0) {
                    filteredData.push(d) }
```

I tried using "require" but it throws an exception about it being undefined. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can change app.js as follows.

```
const fetchData = async (req,res)=> {
    var resp = await Wasabi.find( { publicationDate: { $gte : 2006, $lte : 2016}}).limit(25);
    
    result = [];
    
    resp.forEach(function(data) {
        for(var i in data)
        {
            if(data[i]==null || data[i]=='')
            {
                delete data[i]
            }
        }
        result.push(data)
    })
    
    return result;
};

exports.fetchData  = fetchData;
```

in barchart.js file

```
const { fetchData } = require('./app.js');

const result = fetchData(); // here you can access the result data
```